# Solve differential equation $(xy'+y)^2=x^2y'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation

$$(xy'+y)^2=x^2y'$$

Please  any help. I tried to express one of $x,y,y'$ using other two variables and then solve this. But I get something complicated.

Comment: There's a general solution $y=C-C^2/x$, and a singular solution $y=x/4$. Ask for details only after you provided details (why anybody should consider exactly that equation, for instance), please.

Answer (score 2):

$$(xy'+y)^2=x^2y'$$
$$((xy)')^2=x(xy'+y)-xy$$
Substitute $xy=z$
$$(z')^2=xz'-z $$
Solve this equation 
$$(z')^2-xz'=-z $$
$$(z')^2-xz'+\frac {x^2}{4}=-z +\frac {x^2}{4}$$
$$(z'-\frac {x}{2})^2=-z +\frac {x^2}{4}$$
$$(z'-\frac {x}{2})^2=-(z -\frac {x^2}{4})$$
Substitute $u=(-z +\frac {x^2}{4})$
$$(u')^2=u$$
then integrate this equation $u'= \pm u^{1/2}$

For $u'=u^{1/2}$ you get
$$\boxed{y=K-\frac {K^2}x}$$